# Garbage character displayed while printing web fonts from Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts

I have a problem with printing web fonts from Google chrome v 18 but it works totally fine with IE and Firefox, I am using CSS file to pass the web fonts and the code for it is as follows.

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'C39P24DmTtNormal';
src: url('WebFonts/v100025_-webfont.eot');
src: url('WebFonts/v100025_-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('WebFonts/v100025_-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('WebFonts/v100025_-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('WebFonts/v100025_-webfont.svg#C39P24DmTtNormal') format('svg');

font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Issue Screen-Shot:

[image]

Image Description:

In the above screen-shot all the ones marked in red are the bar-codes provided by the web fonts in CSS file but while printing are shown as above.

I tried to search on Google, but it seems to be a [possible bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98011) with Chrome and they are trying to fix it as soon as they can.

Is there any kind of workaround that can help me as I don't want my clients to install the fonts on each and every computer they use to browse my web application.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug/issue in Chromium?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98011

Comment: Is this happening in print preview like the issue or normally? A screenshot could also be helpful.

Comment: first there was an issue with the print preview as the preview was fired before the data on the page is loaded so i disabled the print preview from the settings, that issue was solved but now the problem starts while printing command is fired.

Comment: In the Chrome bug report, one of the comments mentions using Chrome 15. Perhaps updating Chrome will help? I'm on Chrome v18 and the fonts mentioned in the bug seem to display properly for me.

Comment: i am also using the same chrome 18.0.1025.162 m and still its the same error.

Comment: Please provide an example web page we can access with our browsers to reproduce the problem.  You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ if you do not have a better place to host one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem of disabled print preview from the settings but the problem in Google Chrome. It does not allow the web fonts to get loaded before printing, so just enable it back.

If you are using `Windows.print` on `body.onLoad` then remove that as its the real cause of the problem. This is only supported by Internet Explorer and not Google Chrome.

Example:

```
<body onload="window.print();">
```

Remove the `onload` and I hope it does the trick. If you have tried this then I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Put `.svg` at the start of the sources and try with different formats, like `.svg` as `truetype`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'EnzoOT-Medi';
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: url('font.svg') format('truetype'),
         url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('font.woff') format('woff'),
      url('font.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('font.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but its the same result nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the use of relative font-size in vw. I put a rule in  @media print {}  with size in pt and worked perfect. The funny thing was that it was only happening in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The real fix for this issue is to not load the webfonts async on preformatted print pages. Doing so you can still use `window.onload = window.print()` to force the print dialog without any issues.

```html
<script>
  WebFontConfig = {
    typekit: { id: 'xxxxxx' }
  };

  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
              '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'false';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();
</script>
```