# Google Chrome not printing web fonts correctly

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

When printing pages from Google Google chrome, the print preview looks fine on screen, but the actual printed sheet has garbled characters.

I've found plenty of people that have had this same problem on screen, but none that have had the issue only on the actual printed page:

- [Garbage character displayed while printing web fonts from Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173328/garbage-character-displayed-while-printing-web-fonts-from-google-chrome)

I am embedding my fonts using the fonts.com api. I'm using Chrome 23.0.1271.64 on Mac OSX

Has anyone run into similar problem? Any recommendations?

Comment: I also experience this in Chrome 35 (and previous versions) on both Mac and PC, both with Google Fonts and TypeKit fonts.